# How to Access Azure Databricks APIs from Azure API management as backend without PAT

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-api-management

We need to call Azure Databricks API from Azure API management. With PAT token we are able to call Databrick's API, but we don't need to pass any PAT token, we need to execute API with other ways of authentication. Please suggest a way to authenticate without PAT or any other intrection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Azure Active Directory authentication for that - generate a single AAD token for resource `2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d` if your service principal is already inside the workspace (if it's not, you may need to add more headers). See this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/service-prin-aad-token#get-token) for reference.